# Symfony doctrine repository order by count

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, repository

I have few tables, and get resuts for it.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
$qb->select("a, c, ac")
   ->leftJoin('a.categories', 'c')
   ->leftJoin('a.comments', 'ac')
   ->where('c.slug = :category')
   ->setParameter('category', $category)
   ->orderBy('a.name', 'ASC');
return $qb->getQuery();
```

I want this result, order by comments (ac) count. How can I solve this?

Comment: `->addOrderBy('count(a.comments)', 'ASC');` ?

Comment: I have a error. 
       QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 173: Error: Expected end of string, got '('

 QueryException: SELECT a, c, ac FROM ArticleBundle\Entity\Article a LEFT JOIN a.categories c LEFT JOIN a.comments ac WHERE c.slug = :category ORDER BY count(a.comments) ASC

Comment: Article and Comments have OneTomany relations

/**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $comments;

Comment: remove ";" after your last orderBy and put my line

Comment: I got same error :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
$qb->select("a, c, ac, count(a.comments) AS HIDDEN nbcomments")
   ->leftJoin('a.categories', 'c')
   ->leftJoin('a.comments', 'ac')
   ->where('c.slug = :category')
   ->setParameter('category', $category)
   ->orderBy('a.name', 'ASC')
   ->addOrderBy('nbcomments', 'ASC');
return $qb->getQuery();
```

Comment: I got same error: QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 173: Error: Expected end of string, got '('

Comment: @MindaugasMG have you seen and tried this updated answer?